# Getting error Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true

Tags: session, kentico

I upgraded Kentico site into version Kentico version 11. I am getting error of

> Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the \ section in the application configuration.

I performed solution for that:

1. I applied in web.config

   ```
   sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" mode="InProc" 
   sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes"
   stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" timeout="20"
   ```

   but not working.
2. I also added in page tag in web.config

   ```
   pages enableSessionState="true" validateRequest="false" clientIDMode="AutoID"
   controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"
   ```

   but not working.
3. I also start ASP.Net services but not working.

My .Net framework is 4.6

Answer (score 0):

Correction on my last post now that i have a normal web.config in front of me.

Default Session State is:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
```

Nothing else on the pages part.  Try that.  Emphasis on the cookieless="false" as that is different than your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

at your web.config add the following

`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
.
.
.
.
</modules>`